# How to make zip command line exit when trying to zip a file that doesn't exist

Tags: shell, zip, file-not-found

I'm trying to `zip` several file into one archive.
e.g in my working directory there's `2.txt` but no `1.txt`:

```
$ zip -r 1.zip 1.txt 2.txt
zip warning: name not matched: 1.txt
adding: 2.txt (stored 0%)
$ echo $?
0
```

Is there any way for me to force `zip` to exit if one of the files doesn't exist, instead of just printing a warning like it currently does?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `zip(1)` man page:

> ```
>    -MM
>    --must-match
>           All input patterns must match at least one file  and  all  input
>           files  found  must  be readable.
> ```